# How to change dlsym() return pointer value

Tags: c, dlopen, dlsym

I am trying to find `connect`  symbol in `libcrypto.so` file using dlsym() and want to replace this `connect` with my method.

```
void * lib_orig_tols  = dlopen(libcrypto.so, RTLD_GLOBAL);   

void * p_orig_connectOriginal;
     p_orig_connectOriginal = (void*)dlsym(lib_orig_tols, "connect");

    if (p_orig_connectOriginal != NULL)
        {
        LOGI(" is not NULL");

        void *p_orig_connect = (void*)*((unsigned *)p_orig_connectOriginal);

        *((unsigned *)p_orig_connectOriginal) = (unsigned)( my_crypto_connect);
        }


    int my_crypto_connect(int , const struct sockaddr , socklen_t){
        **
        ***********
        ***************
        **********
    }
```

My my app got crashed with  error
`is not NULL`

`Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0xb6e4755d in tid 7909`

do i am doing something wrong.

Comment: Why is android tagged?

Comment: Please correct the indentation of your code. You must use function pointers. A `unsigned*` is not a valid function pointer.

Comment: 1. You can't do that 2. This code doesn't make sense even if you could do that.

Comment: Redx, app did not crashed this point it crashed when i try to initialize the new value in   ` *((unsigned *)p_orig_connectOriginal) = (unsigned)( my_crypto_connect); `   

later i am typecasting `p_orig_connectOriginal` into function pointer.

Comment: @hobbs : i want to replace system SO function with my function. So when any app call  this SO `connect` then i will get that call.

Comment: This is something that malware would try to do, so there are measures in place to prevent it. One of those would be to make code memory pages read-only. What are you really trying to achieve, maybe there are better ways to do this?

Comment: if the signature of the `connect()` function is `int connect(int , const struct sockaddr* , socklen_t)` , you simply do  `int (*my_connect_ptr)(int , const struct sockaddr , socklen_t) = p_orig_connectOriginal;` instead of the strange casting and dereferencing involving an `unsigned int ` , however libcrypto.so should not have a connect() functon - connect() resides in libc, so you'll likely get that function instead (libcrypto have a `BIO_s_connect/()` tough, with quite a different signature.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your code is incomplete, it is full with syntactical errors, also it contains bogus typecasts (use `intptr_t`)

Plus, there is no 'connect' in libcrypto.so. Pick one from these:

```
BIO_CONNECT_free
BIO_CONNECT_new
BIO_new_connect
BIO_s_connect
```

Comment: I want  to do swizzling in this code. want to change system SO `connect` function  with my `connect` function. So when any application call that `connect` i got the call. after some modification i am calling the SO `connect` using it original function  pointer.

Comment: I don't understand the "SO" part, but it is perfectly possible -- of course you are not supposed to overwrite share code and other nonsense. Here is an example: http://tsocks.sourceforge.net/